# How to format a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have extracted an email and save it to a text file that is not properly formatted. How to remove unwanted line spacing and paragraph spacing?

The file looks like this:

```
                Hi Kim,
               



                     Hope you are fine.
                



                  Your Code is:
                 

                    42483423



                 Thanks and Regards,
                        

                    Bolt
```

I want to open and edit this file and arrange it in a proper format removing all the spaces before the text and below the text in the proper format like:

```
Hi Kim,
Hope you are fine.
Your Code is:
42483423
Thanks and Regards,
Bolt
```

My start procedure,

```
file = open('email.txt','rw')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
re.sub('\s\s+', '\n', s)
```

Comment: Certainly efficient, but if the input had multiple spaces between words, they would become newlines (e.g. "Hi<sp><sp><sp>Kim" becomes "Hi\nKim") which may not be desired.

Answer (score 2):

We can read the input file line by line and ignore the rows which do not have anything but spaces and newlines. Finally, we output the filtered lines with a new line at the end.

```
with open("output_file.txt", "w") as fw:
    with open("email.txt") as fr:
            for row in fr:
                r_s = row.strip()
                if len(r_s):
                    fw.write(r_s+"\n")
```

The output_file.txt is as follows:

```
Hi Kim,
Hope you are fine.
Your Code is:
42483423
Thanks and Regards,
Bolt
```

If we must retain the same file, we can rename the `output_file.txt` with `os.rename`

```
import os
os.rename('output_file.txt','email.txt')
```

EDIT: `if len(r_s)` is a more consise way compared to `if len(r_s) > 0` as pointed out by user: [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) in the comments.

Comment: just `if r_s:` instead of `if len(r_s) > 0:` is just fine.

Comment: @buran thanks for highlighting! still getting used to the conciseness of python :) I have incorporated your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the entire text in a single string (`s`), you could do something like this:

```
formatted = "\n".join(filter(None, (x.strip() for x in s.split("\n"))))
```

That:

- splits the string into separate lines
- strips any leading and trailing whitespace
- filters out empty strings
- rejoins into a multi-line string

Result:

```
Hi Kim,
Hope you are fine.
Your Code is:
42483423
Thanks and Regards,
Bolt
```